# Heatmap gradient changes when multiple nearby sources?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, heatmap

Here is a Heatmap with one source `(weight=0.3)` :

[image]

And here is a Heatmap with multiple sources `(weight=0.3)` :

[image]

I use Heatmap to represent pollution level. And when I have 4 sources with weight of `0.3` (image2) I expect the same green color as on the image1.

But because Heatmaps are used mostly to represent density, they add these sources weights.

**How can I prevent this from happening?**

**Note:** I am using Google Maps Api

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `maxIntensity`. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer):

> maxIntensity: The maximum intensity of the heatmap. By default,
>   heatmap colors are dynamically scaled according to the greatest
>   concentration of points at any particular pixel on the map. This
>   property allows you to specify a fixed maximum. Setting the maximum
>   intensity can be helpful when your dataset contains a few outliers
>   with an unusually high intensity.

The more points you add, the more intense the heatmap will be. Therefore, if you don't want the color to change, you can specify a low maximum intensity so it will always be green.